# Appium - Android device issue

Tags: appium

I have the appium server installed in a remote machine and the android device & tests  in a local machine.my requirement is like need to start the appium server in the remote machine and execute the test on android devices in local machine .

please share your thoughts

Comment: Tough to say what you want us to answer; I'm not entirely sure if you've asked a question.

Comment: I have the above mentioned set up..question i , is it possible to run the test cases on a android devices/ emulator installed in my machine. but the appium server is in a remote server. How does the appium communicate with the android emulator/device

Comment: do i need to have the appium server running on the machine that the device is connected to..?

Comment: // , Hi, @jayesh, could you add some more details, including command line output of your current efforts, to this? Also, some of your comments could be added to this question. You seem like a smart person, good addition to the community.

Comment: I have below thing already been reday - *configured appium and android emulator in a windows machine*I have written the selenium test repo [maven]in git with testng frameworks.*I have a jenkins job to automate the testing*once trigger the job will check out the code from git and run the tests [this happens in a selenuim grid] in the emulator installed in windows machine. the emulator will automatically registter in selenuim grid when the appium starts and will generate a detailed report.

Answer (score 2):

you can execute the way you have mentioned above. provide you should enter the ip address of the local machine where you need to run , while setting the capabilities

```
capa = new DesiredCapabilities();    
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capa);
```

replace 127.0.0.1 with you machine ip. Appium will contact through the ip even if its different machine

Answer (score 2):

The device/emulator must be connected to the same machine that launches the Appium Server.

For real devices Appium communicates with the tested device with the help of adb (Android Debug Bridge) or Xcode via USB-connection. For emulators/simulators the connection similarly must be on the machine that hosts the Appium.

If you're able to provide the same connection to the device remotely so that the machine hosting the Appium server can see the device, then of course it would then be able to automate the device remotely as well.